# Excel: Match returns error

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I have this list in excel:

```
ID (A) | Name (B)
1      | xyz
2      | Yzx s.r.o
3      | xxx a.s.
...
```

In another list, I have only names and need to assign IDs to them based on the list above.

I use this function `=Match(H4; ListName!B2:B50; 0)` (H4 cell contains name of company I want to match from other list and get ID for it).

**When**
**there is no match**, match function returns #Nedostupný (#Not available)
**there is a match**, match function returns #Názov? (#Name?)

EDIT: what could cause this problem? Does Match function works with strings that contains whitespaces, dots, or other special characters? Does a column type matter (whether format is set to text or not)... ?
PS: I wanted to get number of row where there is a match and then just select ID from A column of same row. Is there an easier way? How would I combine column Name with row returned from match? something like `=A+Match(...)`?

Comment: I think you should use `Czech` equvalent of `MATCH` : `POZVYHLEDAT`. See http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=english-czech.html for more details. BTW< for returning corresponding value from column `A` use `=INDEX(ListName!A2:A50;POZVYHLEDAT(H4; ListName!B2:B50; 0))`

Comment: I dont have there such an equivalent. But Match is supported, just returns error and I dont understand why or how to get rid of it.

Comment: From your error messages `#Nedostupný` and `#Názov?` I see that you're using non English version of excel. So, you should use your local functions

Answer (score 0):

1. Like simoco said above, you might have problem with localized function name.
2. You should **always** use fixed references to lookup lists, like this: `=Match(H4; ListName!$B$2:B$50$; 0)` or this: `=Match(H4; ListName!$B:$B; 0)` otherwise when you fill the formula down the list reference will also move down: `=Match(H4; ListName!B3:B51; 0)`, `=Match(H4; ListName!B4:B52; 0)` etc. so it will not contain the data you need.
3. To combine or rather concatenate strings, use `&` operator: `="A"&MATCH(...)`.
4. Probably you should consider using `VLOOKUP()` function instead of `MATCH()` it returns the value from another column based on the search in first column rather than the number position of value you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the syntax of your function is incorrect - the MATCH function uses a comma (,) as the separator between individual arguments, ***not*** semicolons (;).

Secondly, you should use absolute cell referencing for your lookup array in the MATCH function.

Thirdly, you need to ensure that the worksheet in which your lookup array is stored is called ListName (i.e. the same as that referenced in your formula); there shouldn't be any spaces in your worksheet name (e.g. List Name, etc), as this will prevent Excel from referencing the correct worksheet in your workbook [I'm assuming that you are calling the MATCH function from within the same workbook (though not necessarily the same worksheet) as your lookup array].

Hence, your MATCH function should read:

```
=Match(H4,ListName!$B$2:$B$50,0)
```

And I've checked this code - it works perfectly for your intended purpose (as described in your question above) when using either Excel 2010 or Excel 2013.

Comment: I thougth that semicolons were used to separate arguments in some non-English language versions of Excel, because the comma is used as the decimal separator in those countries.

Comment: @nekomatic: Possibly ... I wouldn't be well-versed on other language versions of Excel (since I don't use them myself). But if the OP is intending to use `MATCH` as he/she has written out in the initial post above, the `MATCH` function only accepts comma as its argument delimiter (not semicolons) else it would likely return a `#NAME` error since there is no such function as `MATCH` which uses semicolons as its delimiter.